# Simple code doesn't output all required results

Tags: java, pow

I have Java code that does the following:
1. Works with all combinations of integers `a,b` from `2` to `100` in sets of two. For instance, `2,2`, `2,3`,`...`,`100,100`. I just use two `for` loops for that.
2. For each set, checks whether the `gcd` of both integers is `1` (ignores sets where the `gcd` is 2 or more). I use the `BigInteger` Class because it has a method for that.
3. If the `gcd` is `1`, check whether each of the two integers can be reconciled into a perfect power of base`2` or more and exponent `3` or more. This is how I do that: For instance, let's consider the set `8,27`. First, the code finds the `max` of the two. Then, for this set, the maximum power we can check for is `Math.log10(27)/Math.log10(2)` because the least the base can be is `2`. This is just a trick from the field of mathematics. Hold that in variable `powlim`. I then use a `for` loop and `Math.pow` to check if all of the two integers have perfect `nth` roots like so;

```java
for (double power = 3; power <= powlim; power++) {
      double roota = Math.pow(a, 1.0 / power);
      double rootb = Math.pow(b, 1.0 / power);

if ((Math.pow(Math.round(roota), power) == a) == true &&
   (Math.pow(Math.round(rootb), power) == b) == true) {

if (a < b) {
        System.out.println(a + "\t" + b);
           }
}
```

4. The `a<b` condition makes sure that I don't get duplicate values such as both `8,27` and `27,8`. For my purposes, the two are one and the same thing. Below is the entire code:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int a = 2; a <= 100; a++) {
        for (int b = 2; b <= 100; b++) {
            BigInteger newa = BigInteger.valueOf(a);
            BigInteger newb = BigInteger.valueOf(b);
            BigInteger thegcd = newa.gcd(newb);
            if (thegcd.compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) == 0) {
                double highest = Math.max(a, b);
                double powlim = (Math.log10(highest) / Math.log10(2.0));

                for (double power = 3; power <= powlim; power++) {
                    double roota = Math.pow(a, 1.0 / power);
                    double rootb = Math.pow(b, 1.0 / power);

                    if ((Math.pow(Math.round(roota), power) == a) == true
                            && (Math.pow(Math.round(rootb), power) == b) == true {

                        if (a < b) {
                            System.out.println(a + "\t" + b);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So far so good. The code works fine. However, some few outputs that meet all the above criteria are ignored. For instance, when I run the above code I get;
`8,27`
`16,81`
`27,64`
What I don't understand is why a set like `8,81` is ignored. Its `gcd` is `1` and both of those integers can be expressed as perfect powers of base `2` or more and exponent `3` or more. `8` is `2^3` and `27` is `3^3`. Why does this happen? Alternatively, it's fine if you provide your very own code that accomplishes the same task. I need to investigate how rare (or common) such sets are.

Comment: *FYI:* Please use tabs or 4 spaces for formatting.

Comment: Perhaps you could use a debugger? BlueJ has a debugger that is easy to use, and the IDE is free.

Comment: @akuzminykh fixed and noted, thank you.

Comment: @NomadMaker I will try that once I get the time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Math.pow(b, 1.0 / power); for 81 is 4.32
Then you round 4.32, and 4 at the power 3 is 64. 64 is not equal to 81.
What you should be doing is: Math.round(Math.pow(roota, power)) == a

Also, you need to iterate trough the powers of A and B separately, and check if the number can be rooted.
This means an additional check if the rounded-down value of the double is the same as the double. (Meaning the pow 1/3, 1/4 yields an integer result.)

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int a = 2; a <= 100; a++) {
            for (int b = 2; b <= 100; b++) {
                BigInteger newa = BigInteger.valueOf(a);
                BigInteger newb = BigInteger.valueOf(b);
                BigInteger thegcd = newa.gcd(newb);

                if (thegcd.compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) == 0) {
                    double highest = Math.max(a, b);
                    double powlim = (Math.log10(highest) / Math.log10(2.0));

                    for (double powerA = 3; powerA <= powlim; powerA++) {
                        double roota = Math.pow(a, 1.0 / powerA);
                        for (double powerB = 3; powerB <= powlim; powerB++) {
                            double rootb = Math.pow(b, 1.0 / powerB);

                            if (rootb == Math.floor(rootb) && roota == Math.floor(roota))  {
                                if ((Math.round(Math.pow(roota, powerA)) == a) && (Math.round(Math.pow(rootb, powerB)) == b)) {

                                    if (a < b) {
                                        System.out.println(a + "\t" + b);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Now I do get `8,81` but I have lost `27,64`.

Comment: Corrected it now. Try again, and let me know if it is working as expected.